# Scheduled Task that opens browser and loads a web page

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2022

I am migrating web apps from a Windows 2012 R2 server to a Windows 2022 Server.  Part this includes some Scheduled Tasks.  I have a task that opens up a web browser and then loads a specific web page.  It seems to have worked well on the old server but when I migrate (using export task feature) the browser doesnt load.  Do I need to set certain permissions for this.  I have added to environment variables PATH to teh web browser.  I have run with highest privalges enabled

Is there something else I need to do?  Or is it a security feature on Server 2022

I dont seem to get an error msg from it eithier.  I get a task result of 0x41306, which I believe is my stop task if it runs longer than 4 mins.

I also noticed that I cant open up a web browser when im RDP#d into the server since I added the scheduled task.  Could it be a security feature that has kicked in.  Too many attempts from Administrator trying to open an account maybe?

Below is what im doing

TIA

[image]